# htmlunit proxy getting WebSite Blocked / Access to Site Restricted statuscode 403

Tags: java, proxy, htmlunit, nhtmlunit

i am trying to scrape websites with proxy but i get blocked/access denied.

this is my code:

```
this.webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52, "190.132.233.13", 1212);
this.webClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials("username", "password", "", ""));
HtmlPage page = this.webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
```

i am also tried:

```
this.webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52, "190.132.233.13", 1212);
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "190.132.233.13");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1212");
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
this.webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
```

every site i am trying to scrape i am getting:

```
INFO: statusCode=[403] contentType=[text/html]
INFO: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>ERROR: WebSite Blocked / Access to Site Restricted</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Verdana; }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div id="titles">
        <h1>ERROR</h1>
        <h2>WebSite Blocked / Access to Site Restricted</h2>
    </div>
    <hr><br><br>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Sorry, the access to 'http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/' is restricted.</p>
        <p>To avoid abuse/spam, we only allow access to generic sites such as www.google.com</a>.</p>
        <p>You'll be able to access http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ instantly by adding the domain to your whitelist in the control panel.</p>
        <p>To add this domain to the whitelist, please read the getting started info on the control panel.</p>
        <br>
        <p>You may also request to remove this restriction and have full web access by contacting support.</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
    </body>
    <!-- squid ERR_ACCESS_DENIED -->
    </html>
```

I didn't understand what is the use of getCredentialsProvider function.
thanks for the help. the proxy i use is private proxy.

Comment: Since the used proxy is not public, you need to provide comparison between the HTTP headers using HtmlUnit and the HTTP headers of a real browser.

Comment: You should also use `new NTCredentials("username", "password", null, null)`